# Cannot save integer if it is empty

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, linq-to-sql

i'm developing a form to insert data in the Database (SQlServer 2005) i use Linq to Sql in WPF;

I have this database :

```
Column Name             Data Type          Allow Null
  CODE ID               Int(autoIncr)          No
  BoatName              Nvarchar(100)          No
  BoatType              Nvarchar(50)           yes
  NumberOfSeats         Int                    yes
 And so on...
```

Now when i insert a new record in my form if i leave  empty the  TextBox "txtNumberOfSeats" that refer to field "NumberOfSeat" in the database
and when  i click the button Save the database give me this error:"Input string was not in a correct format."

Why i cannot leave the field "NumberOfSeats "  empty if i set up it in database AllowNull=Yes?

i post the code behind when i click the button Save to insert to new record in the database:

```
DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
Boat_TBL boat = new Boat_TBL();
boat.BoatName = txtBoatName.Text;
boat.BoatType = txtBoatType.Text;
boat.NumberOfSeats = Int32.Parse(txtNumberOfSeats.Text);
dc.Boat_TBLs.InsertOnSubmit(boat);
dc.SubmitChanges;
```

DO you have any suggestion to work out this feature?

Thanks so much

Cheers

Comment: ah yes, the lovely "input string was not in a correct format" error... memories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass null on the Data Access Layer when saving to your DB.
e.g. try something like this:

```
if (String.isNullOrEmpty(txtNumberOfSeats.Text))
{
    NumberOfSeats = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Comment: Hi waqasahmed,i tried your code but i receive this error:"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'int?'"

here is the code:
if (String.isNullOrEmpty(txtNumberOfSeats.Text))
{
    boat.NumberOfSeats = DBNull.Value;// here i receive the error
}

Where i wrong?
However thanks for your suggestion.
Cheers

Comment: int does not convert to DBNULL - You might try using "int?" - the question mark makes it nullable - then when you are adding parameters to your command you can put in logic to pass DBNull.Value instead of null.

Comment: Yes.your advices was useful to work out this step.
Thanks so much for your kind support.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The call to Int32.Parse(...) fails when an empty string is passed to it.  Provided that boat.NumberOfSeats is a nullable int, you should only set it when txtNumberOfSeats.Text is not an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the integer tryParse method and output parameter can be use as no of seats..